# Silverlight page added to html

Tags: asp.net, html, silverlight, xaml

I have a silverlight page and I have a html page with my layout. How can I add the silverlight page to part of my html page? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28VS.95%29.aspx) article tells you how to embed Silverlight.
If you are using Visual Studio to create your Silverlight application, the IDE should create all the code needed to embed the Silverlight control for you.